# Colcon aliases?

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

is there a way to define custom aliases for colcon similarly to [what's possible with catkin tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/verb_customization.html)??

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331039/colcon-aliases-?/) by [artivis](https://answers.ros.org/users/11816/artivis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2019-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`colcon` doesn't offer aliases atm.

While you could create a Python package adding those that would be rather heavy weight for an alias.

You could also define the alias in your shell.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [artivis](https://answers.ros.org/users/11816/artivis/) on 2019-08-19**:
Thanks for the answer. While having shell alias is handy for some cmd, it would still be nice to have aliases for command/verbs or options. E.g. `build --package-up-to` -> `--build-to` or `--event-handlers console_direct+` -> `--verbose` or `--event-handlers console_direct+ --pytest-args -s` -> `--pytest-verbose`, you got the idea.
Marking as correct answer since it does answer the initial question.